# Wrong dimensons on .png-file when using gdal_translate

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal-translate, png

I am using

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -ot UInt16 -scale MIN MAX 0 65535 "source.tiff" "output.png"
```

in the command-prompt to create a .png-file from a .tif-file that I created using the Interpolation-plugin. But when i view the png-file in Windows photo, it has the wrong dimensions, it gets really distorted(squished) in the y-axis, and less noticeably distorted in the x-axis. But if I drag the .png to QGIS it isn't distorted anymore.

This is the output of gdalinfo for the .tif:

`Size is 3000, 3000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,298.257222101],
            EXTENSION["PROJ4_GRIDS","@null"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Origin = (-142.699000000000012,251.647000000000048)
Pixel Size = (0.068380000000000,-0.119760000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    -142.699,     251.647) ( 10d30'35.92"E,  0d 0' 8.17"N)
Lower Left  (    -142.699,    -107.633) ( 10d30'35.92"E,  0d 0' 3.49"S)
Upper Right (      62.441,     251.647) ( 10d30'42.54"E,  0d 0' 8.17"N)
Lower Right (      62.441,    -107.633) ( 10d30'42.54"E,  0d 0' 3.49"S)
Center      ( -40.1290000,  72.0070000) ( 10d30'39.23"E,  0d 0' 2.34"N)
Band 1 Block=3000x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999`

And for the .png:

`Size is 3000, 3000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,298.257222101],
            EXTENSION["PROJ4_GRIDS","@null"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Origin = (-142.699000000000012,251.647000000000048)
Pixel Size = (0.068380000000000,-0.119760000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    -142.699,     251.647) ( 10d30'35.92"E,  0d 0' 8.17"N)
Lower Left  (    -142.699,    -107.633) ( 10d30'35.92"E,  0d 0' 3.49"S)
Upper Right (      62.441,     251.647) ( 10d30'42.54"E,  0d 0' 8.17"N)
Lower Right (      62.441,    -107.633) ( 10d30'42.54"E,  0d 0' 3.49"S)
Center      ( -40.1290000,  72.0070000) ( 10d30'39.23"E,  0d 0' 2.34"N)
Band 1 Block=3000x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999`

Comment: can you add the output of gdalinfo on both the images

Comment: did you try specifying your desired output dimensions with `-outsize` ?

Comment: Val, I tried with -outsize 100% 100% but it did nothing. 

@iant How do I add images in comments?

Comment: Not in percent, rather in pixels. It would be interesting to see the output of `gdalinfo` for your source tiff as @iant requested

Comment: @iant I edited my original question to include the output.

Comment: @Gisnoob123 - it's better to copy & paste the text into the question rather than the images

Comment: I edited the question to include the text instead

Comment: It looks the same to me. When you describe distortion, I take it this is a visual assessment.  How are you viewing the TIFF and PNG images?

Comment: My best guess is that since your geo reference seems to bit out of order, `gdal_translate` tries to estimate the size from the metadata and makes a mistake somewhere, hence the distortions. Maybe try with `-outsize` and a reasonable image size in pixel, not percent.

Comment: @BradHards I am viewing the .tif in QGIS. and the .png in windows default photoviewer.

Comment: @Gisnoob123 So what happens if you open the PNG + .pngw in QGIS?

Comment: When i drag the .png into QGIS it isn't distorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows photo is not a GIS viewer and it does not know anything about georeferencing. Therefore is considers pixels as square.

However, as you can see from the gdalinfo report the pixel x and y size are not equal

```
Pixel Size = (0.068380000000000,-0.119760000000000)
```

I would say that you image is correct, QGIS is doing the right thing as GIS viewer and Windows photo is doing the right thing as photo viewer. If you want that image looks more natural with the photo viewer it should work simply by making the pixels square with gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of png -tr 0.06838 0.06838 input.tif output.png
```

I guess that you have on-the-fly projection turned on in QGIS. If you disable it you should see the same squished image than with the photo viewer.