# QGIS 3.34.1 save several layers in *.jpg with original image resolution

Tags: qgis, export

I have a composition of TIFF images in QGIS 3.34.1 (resolution 30 m):

[image]

There are 6 layers superimposed here and I want to save this composition in JPG/TIFF with preserving the original resolution 30m.

To do this, I tried to do it like [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257585/203997), but this way I can save only one layer.

And then how can I save several layers in JPG/TIFF so that the original resolution 30m is preserved?

Comment: The title of the question is very misleading, you might want to phrase that better since the question has nothing to do with a QGIS "project" (i.e. .qgs .qgz).

Comment: Well, I'm fixed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create a virtual raster `Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster...` and merge all your input images there. Then, you can export the singular output virtual raster layer to TIFF by right-clicking on it `-> Export -> Save As ...`
Here you can specify the output resolution, in your case keep it as "Layer Resolution"

[image]

For JPG you could convert the TIFF using a separate piece of software, or try [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26249/172108).

Comment: Thanks, it worked, just a little bit not as I expected. The Build Virtual Raster tool arbitrarily changes the order of the layers to be combined, but this is a topic for another question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/473732/qgis-3-34-1-build-virtual-raster-from-several-layers-with-predefined-order).